# Cannot compile application under Any CPU platform when using specific x64 library?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, visual-studio

So I have been creating a C# application under Visual Studio 2015 for some time now. In the beginning I was writing classes to interact with hardware via USB libraries provided by the manufacturer and now I am at the higher level and writing classes to do some MatLab data processing.

When I was implementing the classes to interact with the hardware I found that some of the libraries I had were targeted for x86 or x64 and compiling against one or the other platforms broke my usage of the libraries that used the alternate paltform. I found that if I used the Any CPU platform that my application would compile, which simply made me content and I did not read any further into it at the time.

**This is possible correct? You can mix x86 and x64 library usage? Or did I seriously misread documentation?**

Though now I have come to the point that I would like to use a library called `MWArray` which is provided by MathWorks to transfer data to and from MatLab scripts that are compiled to .NET libraries via the MatLab Compiler SDK toolbox.

After some testing I have found that the `MWArray` library will only compile under x64 (though untested I imagine if you had a x86 version it would do the same).

**Seeing as I am using x64 and x86 libraries right now successfully what makes this library special that it will not compile under Any CPU?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not mix 32-bit and 64-bit assemblies in the same process.

Sure, it may compile but it will definitely not run unless you specifically avoid loading the incorrect type of assembly at runtime.

In other words, if your 64-bit process (ie. Any CPU program being run on a 64-bit processor in a 64-bit operating system) attempts to load a 32-bit assembly you will get an exception.

Likewise, if you simply switch 64 and 32 in the above statement, that will hold true for the opposite combination.

Comment: you can mix some 32 bit assemblies to run on a 64bit OS for example with the Oracle.DataClient the 32 bit version runs on 64 bit OS by setting to x86.

Comment: You can run 32-bit processes on a 64-bit OS but you cannot mix 32-bit and 64-bit *in the same process*.

Comment: after reading your answer again.. you are definitely correct.. I misread the original question cheers :) `+1`